# Vuejs: Store variable alias / null cheks

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Id like to use a shorter name than "store.selectedNode.displayName" in my components

Instead of:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useStore } from '@/util/store'
const store = useStore()
</script>

<template>
    <div v-if="store.selectedNode != null">
    <input v-model="store.selectedNode.displayName">
    <input v-model="store.selectedNode.browseName">
```

I would prefer:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useStore } from '@/util/store'
const store = useStore()
assert(store.selectedNode)
const node = reactive(store.selectedNode)
</script>

<template>
    <div>
    <input v-model="node.displayName">
    <input v-model="node.browseName">
```

However, assert doesnt seem to work inside  tags here - compiler still complain about store.selectedNode might be null.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

`store.selectedNode` is already reactive. You're looking for `!` non-null assertion operator. As long as `selectedNode` remains the same object through the component's lifespan, it can be:

```
assert(store.selectedNode)
const { browseName, displayName } = toRefs(store.selectedNode!);
```